# How to compile image project for vxworks 6.8 with C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, vxworks

I'm trying to include kernel configuration for all C++ components.
[image: components]

But header iostream isn't visible. Where might be the problem?

Comment: You are apparently trying to include C++ header to C file? These are different programming languages.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site mechanics. Welcome to SO.